# Numpy-like masks in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have to create a mask for all numbers in a tensor that are not equal to -1.

In numpy I would do this:

```
mask = np.ones_like(my_matrix)
mask[my_matrix == -1] = 0
```

How can I achieve the same in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

mask = tf.not_equal(my_matrix, -1)